# NoMethodError when using the paperclip gem in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, paperclip

I am trying to upload an image using the paperclip gem and imagemagick in rails. I did everything I was supposed to do and I get the following error message when I try to upload. It is a NoMethodError.  [Error message screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Meoi.png)

My gem file:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '4.2.3'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'simple_form', '~> 3.4'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'devise', '~> 4.2', '>= 4.2.1'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.4.1'
gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'paperclip', '~> 5.1'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'bcrypt', git: 'https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby.git', :require => 'bcrypt'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

My _form.html.erb file:

```
<%= simple_form_for @book, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
    <%= select_tag(:category_idd, options_for_select(@categories), :prompt=> "Select a category")%>
    <%= f.file_field :book_img%>
    <%= f.input :title, label: "Book title" %>
    <%= f.input :description, label: "Please describe your book here"%>
    <%= f.input :author, label: "Who is the author of this book?" %>
    <%= f.button :submit%>
<% end %>
```

My development.rb file:

```
Rails.application.configure do

  Paperclip.options[:command_path] = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin'

  config.cache_classes = false

  config.eager_load = false


  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  config.assets.debug = true

  config.assets.digest = true


  config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true

end
```

My book.rb file:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :category

    has_attached_file :book_img, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
    validates_attachment_content_type :book_img, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/
end
```

My book_controller file:

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
    before_action :find_book, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

    def index
        if params[:category].blank?
            @books = Book.all.order("created_at DESC")
        else
            @category_idd = Category.find_by(name: params[:category]).id
            @books = Book.where(:category_idd => @category_idd).order("created_at DESC")
        end
    end
    def show
    end

    def new
        @book = current_user.books.build
        @categories = Category.all.map{ |c| [c.name, c.id]}
    end

    def create
        @book = current_user.books.build(book_params)
        @book.category_idd = params[:category_idd]

        if @book.save
            redirect_to root_path
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def edit
        @categories = Category.all.map{ |c| [c.name, c.id]}
    end

    def update
        @book.category_idd = params[:category_idd]
        if @book.update(book_params)
            redirect_to book_path(@book)
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @book.destroy
        redirect_to root_path
    end

    private

        def book_params
            params.require(:book).permit(:title, :description, :author, :category_idd, :book_img)
        end

        def find_book
            @book = Book.find(params[:id])
        end
end
```

A thing to note, when I remove ":book_image" from the book_params in the book_controller, the error disappears , but I don't think it actually uploads the image since the book params has to have the ":book_img" part in it. Help would be highly appreciated since this is driving me crazy.

EDIT:
After removing the :book_img from book_params in the books_controller, I tried submitting a form with an image attached. I get no error, but when I go to the rails console and see the data in the last uploaded book, they show the data related to "book_img" are all "nil". So even though the error disappeared, the image was not uploaded.

EDIT2: Iceman, I get the following error:[Error image screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pM7Sg.png)

Comment: Could you post the log file for when the `create` method is called?

Comment: Hey Jaime, I don't get the error anymore because I added the code iceman told me to add(the answer below us), It made the error disappear, but it didn't actually upload the image. Right now, I have set it in such a way that when I click on "add book", it will take me to the root_path (the home page), if the book is saved, if not, it will render "new". When I added your code, it removed the error but it keeps rendering "new", because the book with the attached image cannot be saved. But if I create a book with no image attached, it will save the book and take me to the homepage

Comment: But Rails should still be saving logs. If you're running your application by using `rails server`, you should see the log in your terminal window. If you're running it some other way, you should find the logs in your project folder `log/environment.log`. The answer you're looking for will probably be there

Comment: @JaimeRodas So the problem appear to be  "Content type spoof: Filename scsc.png (image/png from Headers, [#<MIME::Type: image/png>] from Extension), content type discovered from file command: . See documentation to allow this combination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part is the problem, when the `@book` is not saved the form is re-rendered and `@categories` is `nil`. Add a call to fetch `@categories` and you should be good to go.

```
if @book.save
  redirect_to root_path
else
  @categories = Category.pluck(:name, :id)
  render 'new'
end
```

Comment: Hey Man, thank you for that. It made the error disappear, but it didn't actually upload the image. Right now, I have set it in such a way that when I click on "add book", it will take me to the root_path (the home page), if the book is saved, if not, it will render "new". When I added your code, it removed the error but it keeps rendering "new", because the book with the attached image cannot be saved. But if I create a book with no image attached, it will save the book and take me to the homepage.

Comment: Try `save!` to get an exception, then you will see your error.

Comment: Well, yes, that is a totally different issue, something to do with the file you're trying to upload. I suggest you ask a new question for that.

Comment: Yes, sir. Will do

Comment: Please check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43824679/paperclip-combined-with-imagemagick-saves-images-but-doesnt-display-them-on-the