# Paperclip combined with Imagemagick saves images but doesn't display them on the site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I am using paperclip and Imagemagick to add images to a website. I have a form on the site for users to upload images. When I upload an image, it doesn't give any errors. When I check the rails console, the image is saved with the right size and all that. When I check the project folder, the images get saved in there too. But when I try to display, I get the following screen on the site(Only one image has been added, only the one on the left is supposed to show up, the missing tags on the rest are because no images are added there):[Screenshot of screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZjKL.png)

This is my index.html page:

```
<h1 class="current-category"><%= params[:category]%></h1>

<% if @books.count == 0 %>
    <h1>There are no books currently in this category</h1>
<%else%>
    <% @books.each do |book| %>
        <a href="/books/<%= book.id %>">
            <%= image_tag book.book_img.url(:book_index) %>
        </a>
    <% end %>
<%end%>
```

And I get the following error message on the terminal window:[Screenshot of terminal window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Pqn6.png)

Please let me know why this is happening. Thank you.

Comment: What url does it generate when u see in console? `avatar.url`?

Comment: The Imagemagick tag seems redundant as you say the images have been created and saved. So the problem must be the path in your display code to the saved image? I would say you need to add some of your code that selects the image.

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon Hey, I have attached a picture of the console. If thats not it, what do you mean by avatar.url?

Comment: That's the error of the `missing.png` which is missing. But as u said, you are concerned about the first image. What are the values in the `image` model not ahowing up? Avatar is nothing but the name of the attachment. `atachment.url`. Or in ur case what is `book.book_img.url`

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon I see what you are saying. I edited my question and added my index.html file. It's "book_img.url".

Comment: I m interested in the value it generates..what's the url?

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon Are you asking me for the website address? I don't have it up and running. It is running locally on my computer. Sorry for the confusion. Please let me know how to find the values and I'll tell them to you

Comment: Type this in your irb console and tell me what it returns.. `BookImg.first.url` I assume it is `BookImg`, if it is not, use your image model `.url`

Comment: I don't have a different model for images, it is an attachment to the books table. The attachment name is book_img.  @Md.FarhanMemon

Comment: I am not a ruby user but I would view the source of the html webpage and see what paths the images have. Or does that not work in ruby?

Comment: @Bonzo that can be done too. View source/inspect element..

Comment: @Bonzo thanks a lot! Turns out my folder was named Medium and thumb instead of book_index and book_show. So it was looking for a folder named "book_index" when that folder didn't actually exist. It works now!